# Use c++ to count machine-code instructions executed

Tags: windows, 64-bit

I want to know how to count the number of instructions executed by a c++ program during a sampling period.  I specifically do not want to use a profiler.  I want to add c++ code to said program that will count the # of instructions executed.  I don't know where to start.  Are there processor counters I can sample?

"Instructions" refers to machine-code instructions.  Not the # of statements in the c++ source.

I am asking how to implement this counting myself.  I specifically have been given a task "to count the number of machine-code instructions executed by a program during a sampling period - WITHOUT USING A PROFILER"

Comment: What do you mean by "instructions"? The number of statements in the C++ source? The number of machine-code instructions? Something else in between, or something else completely? And are you asking about how to implements this "counting" yourself, or about tools or libraries that will help you?

Comment: "instructions executed"

Comment: And ***what do you mean*** by "instructions"?

Comment: "mov ax, 10" <-- machine code instruction

Comment: i think i want this: __readpmc

Comment: @johnnycrash This is a good question. I don't understand why the others are asking "what do you mean by instructions?". He means what he says. An instruction is an unambiguous term, especially when he clearly describes what he wants. At any rate, did you figure it out? By a quick look, MSVS docs say that the intrinsic `__readpmc` is only available in kernel mode and doesn't indicate that it will be used for such a purpose, although I may be wrong of course.